# Lemma 10.8 - Rudin's Functional Analysis, simple inequality.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, banach-algebras

From a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390166/lemma-10-8-rudin-functional-analysis-proof) asked by myself long ago apparently:

All the notation is in that question.
There's the inequality

$$
|g(\lambda)| \leq |2r - g(\lambda)|
$$

Which I am not sure where it comes from. Here $g$ is an entire function with the following properties: $g(0) = g'(0) = 0$ and $Re\left[ g(\lambda) \right] \leq |\lambda|$. This last inequality should imply the one I am asking.

Can you help to figure out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $g(\lambda)=a+ib$. In the argument in the posting you quote it is established that  $g(\lambda)$ is in the region $A_\lambda:=\{x+iy: x\leq |\lambda|\}$. If $|\lambda|\leq r$ then $a\leq|\lambda|\leq r$

Then

1. $|g(\lambda)|^2=a^2+b^2$
2. $|2r-g(\lambda)|^2=(2r-a)^2+b^2=4r^2-4ra+a^2+b^2=4r^2-4ra+|g(\lambda)|^2$
3. $4r^2-4ra=4r(r-a)\geq0$

Putting things together, you obtain the desired conclusion.